# Can this be a chinese name?

Tags: names

There is a popular meme online which photoshops John Cena's face onto Mao Zedong, naming it 'Zhong XiNa'.

Is there a possibility that this can be transliterated into a real, meaningful Chinese name?

Answer (score 3):

John Cena's 'Chinese name' is 赵喜娜，its a more of a ridicule than an actual translated name, I mean if you really want it, you can go 钟(An actual Chinese last name)西(West)纳(As in **NA**SDAQ), which is the pinyin of 'Zhong XiNa'.

Comment: Isn't 赵喜娜 a female name? John is a male name.

Comment: that was the joke mate, the reason that he is called this way, iirc was he called Taiwan a country during his fast 9 promotions or stuffs like that.